# Limit question concerning a triangle and its circumcircle

Tags: geometry, limits

$ABC$ is an isosceles triangle ($|AB|=|BC|$). Let $s$ be the length of the altitude from vertex $B$ to side $AC$, and let $m=|AC|$. Given that the radius of the circumcircle of $ABC$ is $2\,\text{cm}$, and the area of the triangle is $k$, calculate:

$$
\displaystyle\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{s^2}{k\cdot m}
$$

---

Obviously, $k=s\cdot m / 2 $. How do I proceed thereafter?

Comment: What do you mean by "Obviously $k=s\cdot m/2$"? Note that $k$ isn't defined in the statement at all.

Comment: @Calvin Sorry, forgot to include $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the observation that $k = sm/2$, we want $\lim \frac{2s}{m^2}$.

**Hint:** Express $s$ in terms of $m$.
By power of a point about the midpoint of $AC$, $ s(4-s) = (m/2) (m/2)$. Hence $ s = \frac{1}{2} \left(4 - \sqrt{16- m^2 }\right) $.

**Hint:** Evaluate $\lim \frac{ 4 - \sqrt{16 - m^2 } } { m^2}$.
There are several ways to do so, like:
1) multiply by the conjugate
2) apply L'hopital's rule.

Comment: Are you sure about $s=2-\sqrt{4-m^2}$ ?

Comment: Fixed the typo, thanks. (I was interchangeably using 2m as the side length to avoid fractions.)